# Python - Read files from folder and Write CSV file in format

Tags: python, csv, file, ordereddict

```
import glob
import os
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

#Remove output file if already exists. Resolve the append Issue
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\Outputs\\LOC3X.csv'
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    os.remove(file_path)
#

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\*.CBL')      # Input files in Folder
Fields = ['Program Name', 'LinesofCode']                   # to be displayed in output CSV file

# opening output csv file to write (Fields)
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\Outputs\\LOC3X.csv'           
with open(file_path, 'a') as csvfile1:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile1)
    csvwriter.writerow(Fields)
    csvfile1.close()

def process_files_loc(list_of_files):
    for fileName in list_of_files:
        with open(fileName) as i:
            count = sum(1 for line in i)
            
            my_dict = {i : count}        #input filename and its lines of code
            ordered_dict = OrderedDict()               #using OrderedDict
            print(ordered_dict)

            # creating ordered dict from dict
            ordered_dict = OrderedDict(my_dict)
            print(ordered_dict)

            # writing records of Program name and LinesofCode to output csv file
            file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\Outputs\\LOC3X.csv'
            with open(file_path, 'a') as csvfile2:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile2)
                csvwriter.writerows(ordered_dict)
                csvfile2.close()
                        
process_files_loc(list_of_files)
```

Output in Teminal (Error):

```
PS C:\Users\Python-1> & C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Python-1/one.py
OrderedDict()
OrderedDict([(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\ABCDEFGH.CBL' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>, 191)])
OrderedDict()
OrderedDict([(<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Cobol\\IJKLMNOP.CBL' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>, 195)])
```

Actual output of file in Folder:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Cobol\Outputs

Name        Date Modified       Type                Size
LOC3X.csv   9/15/2022 time      Comma Seperated     1KB
```

**Problem:** Script executed and Read 2 CBL files in the Folder, and created 1 CSV file in output folder. The output CSV file to have,

```
Program Name    LinesofCode
ABCDEFGH.CBL    191
IJKLMNOP.CBL    195
```

However, the actual output lines in CSV file is,

```
Program Name    LinesofCode
```

Comment: Try just writing the lines as list `csvwriter.writerows([fileName, count])`. Also the `with`will close the file be itself, no need for .close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import glob
import csv
import os


def process_files_loc(files):
    res = []
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            line_count = len([line.strip("\n") for line in f if line != "\n"])
        res.append([os.path.basename(f.name), line_count])
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('C:\\Users\\Main\\Desktop\\test\\test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
        csvwriter.writerow(['Program Name', 'LinesofCode'])
        csvwriter.writerows(process_files_loc(glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Main\\Desktop\\test\\*.PY')))
```

Result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOjx.png)

Regards,

Comment: It worked. Appreciate! your answer, Hachard Victor.